# Add div innerHTML values to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you select 1 innerHTML value from a group of divs below and push the values into an object?

Each div class (one, two) below should work similar to an HTML select box on a form, where only 1 value is stored per class.

I'd like to push 1 value from each div class into an object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>


<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
obj = {};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".one").click(function(){
       var text = $( ".box" ).html();

       obj.var1 = text;
       alert(obj.var1);
    });

    $(".two").click(function(){
       var text = $( ".box" ).html();

       obj.var2 = text;
       alert(text);
    });
});
</script> 


<style type="text/css">
#menu div{
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;   
}



</style>
</head>



<body>



    <div id="content1">

        <div id="menu1">
            <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">A</div></a>
            <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">B</div></a>
            <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">C</div></a>
            <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">D</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <div id="content2">

        <div id="menu2">
            <a href="#2" class="two"><div class="box">E</div></a>
            <a href="#2" class="two"><div class="box">F</div></a>
            <a href="#2" class="two"><div class="box">G</div></a>
            <a href="#2" class="two"><div class="box">H</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique.

Comment: `"document"` should be `document` Without quotes.

Comment: <div id="content"> <div id="menu"> how these id'd repeating it need to be unique

Comment: Alot of correction in post please keep a clean version and if possible post fiddle and ask a clearly what you need to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. Use `document` instead of `"document"`
2. You need to use `.find()` for child box
3. You need to stop default action. So used `return false;` here. You can also use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Use

```
var obj = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".one").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).find(".box").html(); //Find child box
        obj.var1 = text;
        alert(obj.var1);
        return false; //Stop default action
    });

    $(".two").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).find(".box").html();
        obj.var2 = text;
        alert(text);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xfy9/)

Comment: How can I check the 2 values are inside the object?

Comment: @rrrfusco, `if(obj.var1 && obj.var2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('.one.box').on('click', function() {
        obj.var1 = $(this).html();
    }    
    $('.two.box').on('click', function() {
        obj.var2 = $(this).html();
    }
})
```

This code adjusts each div an onClick event, and when its fired it add its html() value to obj.var1 or obj.var2, i hope it helps you, if have any further questions, you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` in you click function, by doing so you can get the text inside the selected div.

```
$(".one").click(function(){
   var text = $(this).find("div").html();

   obj.var1 = text;
   alert(obj.var1);
});

$(".two").click(function(){
   var text = $(this).find("div").html();

   obj.var1 = text;
   alert(obj.var1);
});
```

Note: The `$("document")` should be `$(document)`..